# Wordpress and author__in

Tags: wordpress

I manipulate a query with pre_get_posts

But i want to show posts of multiple authors.

These for i use "author__in".

```
$query->set('author__in', [53, 285]);
```

But my query still runs with 2 post_author parameters. How can i exclude the second one?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.ID IN (349956,327745,177707)
AND wp_posts.post_author IN (53,285)
AND (wp_posts.post_author = 53)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various author filters available: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

Adding a new one won't remove others - so you'll need to remove the original author filter. You can do this using the following code:

```
unset( $query->query_vars['author'] );
```